# Where can I find review materials?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I've got interviews coming up for an internship this summer, and I'd like to review common algorithms and data structures so that I won't be caught off guard by any of the technical questions.

Can anyone recommend a good resource, online or otherwise, for a refresher on common things like shuffling an array, tree traversal, linked lists, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robert Sedgewick's "Algorithms in $language" are a nice source.
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/

And of course, Cormen et. al.'s "Introduction to Algorithms" for a more abstract view
http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=11866

Oh, and of course, can't forget Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming", the definitive compendium...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming

Answer (score 0):

This book has a decent review for the basics along with code samples: [Programming Interviews Exposed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047012167X). MIT has an open courseware algorithms class with video lectures [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-046JFall-2005/VideoLectures/). That goes into way more depth, but you can skip around and pick one what you want. I'm sure just searching google for "algorithms site:.edu" will bring up lots of useful results too.